# Session timeout in php with specific time

Tags: php, session

How can I set a certain time to destroy a session? Can anyone show me the right way to destroy session after 10 minutes? Here is my code:

Session authorization:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) || (trim($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) == '')) {
    header("location: index.php");
    exit();
}
```

Session logout:

```
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']);
unset($_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME']);
unset($_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME']);
header("location: index.php");
```

Session login:

```
if($result) {
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        //Login Successful
        session_regenerate_id();
        $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['id'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID'] = $member['username'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['first_name'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['last_name'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_USER_TYPE'] = $member['acc_type'];
        session_write_close();
        header("location: user_profile.php");
        exit();
    } else {
        header("location: loginerr.php");
        exit();
    }
} else {
    die("Query failed");
}
```

Comment: On front end setTimeout to call ajax function after 10 min, backend script called by ajax invokes session_destroy()

Comment: 10 minutes of inactivity or just 10 minutes? You can't log them out _automatically_ but you can log then out when they attempt access after 10 minutes.

Comment: 10 minutes inactivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, unless you roll your own session handling system. The default session cleanup system is run randomly. Every invocation of a PHP script that calls `session_start()` has a chance of triggering the garbage collector.

When the GC fires up, it basically rolls through the session storage directory and looks for any files which haven't been accessed in more than the default expiry period, and deletes any that are "stale".

By definition, if a session is used (e.g. `session_start()` is called and that particular session file gets loaded), then it cannot be stale and will not be deleted.

You'd need an external system to schedule the deletion, e.g. using the `at` scheduler.

Comment: I would wait for clarification.  You can log them out on access attempt after 10 min, or 10 min of inactivity.  Just not _automatically_ at the 10 min mark.

Comment: I would like to destroy session if anyone inactive for 10 min.

Comment: then set your session timeout for 10 minutes, and whenever the GC starts up, it'll auto-nuke any session files older than 10 minutes.